# Can't keep all data of user in session after login at codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am developing a login method in my project. I can not keep all my user data in the session after login. I can only keep the data which I used for my login.

Like I can keep email and type in my session But I can not keep the name of the user in the session.

**My controller**

```
public function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|alpha_dash');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        /*=== LOAD DYNAMIC CATAGORY ===*/
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $view['category'] = $this->admin_model->get_category();
        /*==============================*/

        $view['user_view'] = "users/login";
        $this->load->view('layouts/user_layout', $view);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');

        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $type = $this->input->post('type');

        $user_data = $this->user_model->login_user($email, $password, $type);

        if($user_data)
        {
            $login_data = array(

                'user_data' => $user_data,
                'email'     => $email,
                'type'      => $type,
                'name'      => $name,
                'logged_in' => true

            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($login_data);
```

**My model**

```
public function login_user($email, $password, $type)
{
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('type', $type);

    $result = $this->db->get('users');

    $db_password = $result->row('password');

    if(password_verify($password, $db_password))
    {
        return $result->row(0)->id;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**I want to keep all data of a user into the session after login. How I can do that?**

Comment: do you want to keep all data from db? 
i mean for example `password`, `created_time`, ... ?

if you want that simple way is to return `$result->row_array();` in model and use that in your controller

Comment: Yes, I want exactly like this. @AliQorbani I used your solution in my model, It can't change anything.

Comment: Where does the value of `$name` come from? I don't see where in `login()` that it is set.

Comment: I want to get this $name from the database row and put it to the session. But I cant. No this is not set anywhere.@DFriend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to having what you want. The biggest problem is with this line

```
return $result->row(0)->id;
```

Because that returns only the value of the `'id'` column. Fix that (and make the code more compact) like this

```
public function login_user($email, $password, $type)
{
    $result = $this->db
        ->where(array('email' => $email, 'type' => $type))
        ->get('users')
        ->row(0); //$result is the whole row - all the columns

    if($result && password_verify($password, $result->password))
    {
        return $result;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then the important part of the controller makes use of getting the whole row with this.

```
$user_data = $this->user_model->login_user($email, $password, $type);

if($user_data)
{
    $login_data = array(
        'user_data' => $user_data,  //all the columns from row(0)
        'email' => $user_data->email, //email column from row(0)
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $user_data->name, // name column from row(0)
        'logged_in' => true
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($login_data);
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem but I am facing problem to get the session id.